# ASP.NET MVC localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I'd like to use resource file (.resx) to do localization in ASP.NET MVC. My thought is:

1. Make a default resource file under App_GlobalResources folder
   Make several local resource files under App_LocalResources folder
2. read cookie info to set CultureInFo
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

then, I'd like to use resource file in controller to set ViewData value, something like:

```
ViewData["Title"] = Resources:Resource, PageTitle;
```

but the syntax is wrong, how can I do this?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried following?

```
ViewData["Title"] = Resources.Resource.PageTitle;
```

If you have `Resource.aspx` file in your `App_GlobalResources` this should work.